# If/else statement in case JSON endpoint doesn’t exists

Tags: javascript, json, if-statement, undefined, endpoint

I am trying to create a scenario where if endpoint doesn’t exists, function still returns a value.

When the endpoint exists, I get a value, no problem.

```
var main = function(){
json_url = "http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/next.json";
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", json_url, false);
xhr.send(null);
weather = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

let race = " ";

if (weather.MRData.RaceTable.Races[0].Sprint.date === undefined) {
  race = " ";
} 
else {
  race = weather.MRData.RaceTable.Races[0].Sprint.date;
}
return race;
}
```

I get the following result

```
2022-07-09
```

But in case the endpoint doesn’t exists, I get a error.

```
var main = function(){
json_url = "http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last.json";
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", json_url, false);
xhr.send(null);
weather = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

let race = " ";

if (weather.MRData.RaceTable.Races[0].Sprint.date === undefined) {
  race = " ";
} 
else {
  race = weather.MRData.RaceTable.Races[0].Sprint.date;
}
return race;
}
```

How can I rectify this. Do I have to assign something other than undefined in this case.

Comment: would help if you shared what the error is. You most likely need to check if `xhr.responseText` has a value in it (ie: isn't `null`)

Comment: I am trying to make this work in a ios app for making widgets so it doesn’t give me detailed error. I only get ‘ Javascript exception occurred’, sorry. Though I can assure you endpoint doesn’t have a value in xhr.responseText

Comment: `weather` will be `null` then if `xhr.responseText` is null. So it will crash when it tries to do read `MRData` on it: `weather.MRData`

Comment: So there is no way to make this work?

Comment: check if `xhr.responseText` is `null` before trying to do stuff with it such as parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Use as below:

```
var main = function(){
json_url = "http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last.json";
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", json_url, false);
xhr.send(null);
weather = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

 return weather.MRData.RaceTable.Races[0].date;
}
```

or:

```
race = weather.MRData.RaceTable.Races[0].FirstPractice.date;
```

or:

```
race = weather.MRData.RaceTable.Races[0].Qualifying.date;
```

Comment: It isn’t working but thanks for trying.

Comment: You can remove if statement. And it will work

Comment: i updated as you can use it